# How to use only one child theme but have custom text for each site

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am using wordpress multisite for 5 websites. I created a child theme off of the parent so all sites have the same theme, but we have a need for slightly different introduction text at the top of the home pages.

The theme I am using has 3 columns but only has widget-able functionality in column 2 and 3, but the main content area does not have a widget area. Otherwise i would have dropped in a text widget for what i want here.

My question is what is the best way to add this text?

1.) Would I do this in functions.txt? Something like if(site1) echo, elsif(site2) echo, or is there an easier way than this?

2.) Is there a way to do this by editing the theme files and using some short of shortcode? But then where would i define what text to place in there based on the site thats loading?

Please provide a simple example in code if possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: On the first sight, why can't you add a widget area for your first column too? see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes

Comment: @BassJobsen That article is a little sparse. What would mine be registered as, cause its not a sidebar? Also once the function is in the functions.php how do i get that data into the theme itself? I.e. how do i call the function. Thanks for an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step 1, add to your function.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Register our sidebars and widgetized areas.
 *
 */
function arphabet_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'Column 1',
        'id' => 'column_1',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="rounded">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init' );
```

step 2, now you will find the widget area in your dashboard Appearance/Widgets, add your content to it.

step 3 add `<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'column_1' ); ?>` in your template where you want to have column 1

Comment: Hey thanks for the example and quick response. I am on travel, and will code this tomorrow and let you know how it went.

Comment: It actually was a better solution than I was thinking. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Beside coding the theme there are also other way maybe easier ...

Use this plugin to create widget zone inside a page: 
Widgets on Pages
Versione 0.0.12 | by Todd Halfpenny

Use this plugin so you can display or not the widget deending on what page you are:
Dynamic Widgets
Versione 1.5.6 | by Qurl

Comment: I will give these plugins a look as well, I like to add tools to my arsenal. I'll take a look tomorrow when I'm back from my travel. Thanks!

Comment: The dynamic widgets plugin is pretty useful.